# Scroll to TableViewHeader using "tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex:" help?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uitableview

I added a search bar into my TableViewController's header, and I've also added a "{search}" to  the "sectionIndexTitlesForTableView" array. Now on the right side, I got the letters of the alphabet + the search symbol on the top... to scroll to the sections of the letters (not the search field) I used this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index{

    return index -1;
}
```

now when I click the letter A, it scrolls to the section A and so on. Only I can't make the "search symbol" scroll to the search bar in the tableView's header...

How can I do this?

Thank you in advance...

[image][image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the Search bar is at the very top of the tableView, you could do something like-

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index{

// as the search icon is at index 0, scroll to the top
    if(index == 0)    
        [tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, searchBar.width, searchBar.height) animated:YES];    
    return index -1;
}
```

Else, if it is a section without any rows, you could do-

```
CGRect searchBarRect = [tableView rectForSection:searchBarIndex];
[tableView scrollRectToVisible:searchBarRect animated:YES];
```

HTH,

Akshay

Comment: Edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: To avoid the need to have a reference to the search bar it is also possible to do the scrolling with just - tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0) - variation of this method with animation option is also available but IMO there should be no animation hence all other navigation by section indexes has none

Answer (score 0):

Are you dealing with xib, if yes then move you search bar top of the UITableView
for example

```
UIView // your main view  
  SearchBar
  UITableView
```

Ok actually your question was not clear to me, now after you comment i expand my answer

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
      {
          // An array of strings that serve as the title of sections
      }
```

> **This datasource method just asks the data source to return the titles for the sections for a table view.**

I would suggest you to [refer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

> according to your picture i will stick again to my previous answer based on usability issue.  why can not you put the search bar stick to top forever, it will just eat one/two result set row (**ok here i am giving the strong suggestion**- if you allow the user to goto searchbar by clicking on your searchicon is not easy(*its very tiny*) sectionIndex title generally user do not use and if they use they just use for to go to particular section directly).

Hope my suggestion may be the good answer for you.

Thanks

Comment: no I've added the search bar into the header programmatically

Comment: Okay then you can set the frame for UISearchBar and add top of the UITableView. :)

Comment: no you don't understand... i want to SCROLL to it, using the indexes on the right (like you have it in the Contacts!).. When you touch "A" on the right, it throws you to section A.... If you touch "T" it scrolls to section T. How can I make it to scroll to the search bar (I already have it!), when I press the search symbol on the right side?

Comment: we don't understand each other.. I've done everything, the sections are there, the search bar in the header and the sections in the sidebar... everything works, except if I click the search symbol in the sidebar, it won't take me to the header!

Comment: i need to get the tableview's header index or something!

Comment: **I think picture can well defined the question to me.**

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with another method of UITableView as below:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{

    if (//this condition is apply for A-Z//) {

    }
    else { //--- This is for your Search symbol---//
        [tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];
    } 
    return (return your desire section value i.e. 1);
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of methods are provided for UITableView for some specific work. So concentrate on it and choose your best. This method is good for you because u use search bar in header of table view. So your search bar is now also part of your table view. By using above method you reposition your table view and show search bar on click of search symbol.