# can I show an index for UITableView (ie sectionIndexTitlesForTableView) without a searchbar?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to make an bunch of links on the right side of the uitableview to jump to the various sections in the tableview without having a searchbar at the top.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure can. Just implement a couple of methods in your table view’s data source: `-sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:`, which should return an array of titles, and `-tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex:`, which returns the corresponding section once the user clicks on a section title.

Comment: It only displays when I have the searchbox open. I would like to get to this: (2nd picture)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994480/scroll-to-tableviewheader-using-tableviewsectionforsectionindextitleatindex

Comment: Sounds like you’re adding that code to the wrong view controller, then.